# Create ListView with Inline Editing for Related Object

Tags: lightning, list-view

I have a custom object called Renovation and a child object called Renovation Element.  I want to create a ListView on the Renovation Lightning Page with inline editing enabled that has a list of the Renovation Elements.  The Renovation Element custom object is not available to be chosen in the Object Drop Down List when creating the list view.  Why is that?  How do I create a New List View of Renovation Elements that are related to the Renovation?  FYI, I have Inline Editing enabled and also enhanced lists enabled in the org.

Comment: This is not clear - do you want to show the `Renovation Element` related list on the standard `Renovation` record page? you need to add the `Renovation Element` list to the `Renovation` page layout. Else - what exactly do you want to see and where (please point out standard or not)

Comment: That is correct, I want to show a ListView of related records.  I found out this is not possible to do in Salesforce.

Comment: Of course this is possible.  It is pretty basic. Do that from the page layout setting.

Comment: Correct, it is possible to have a list of related record but it is not possible to have a list of related records with inline editing.

Comment: Seems like it's not yet possible without code --> link to Idea (https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BpXFAA0)